# Visual studio code key binding - changing focus from terminal to editor

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm wondering, how to set behavior of changing focus from integrated terminal into editor in Visual Studio Code. I'd like to have such binding on "escape" key (like in Intellij).
I had this configuration:

```
{
    "key": "escape",
    "command": "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

And it worked. But there is a caveat: If I'm editing any file in vim in integrated console, then I cannot quit vim edit mode with escape, because focus is moved to editor (instead of exiting vim mode).
I think I'm missing some condition in [when clause](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_contexts). I was thinking about this:

```
"when": "terminalFocus && !isInEmbeddedEditor"
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: does IntelliJ know that you have started vim in an integrated terminal and does not capture `Esc`? Use a different keybinding like `Ctrl+Esc`

Comment: I don't know, how Intellij internally handles it. Probably it's like you're saying: it does not capture `Esc` when in vim in integrated terminal.
I can bind to `Ctrl+Esc`, but it sounds like a workaround.